# Airport command line utility only shows man page in macOS 10.12.2

Tags: command-line, macos, airport

In previous iterations of OSX, I've been able to use the command line utility without issue. Now, no matter what the parameter I send, it shows me the --help output:

```
[andrew@mba] /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport en1 sniff 1
Usage: airport <interface> <verb> <options>

    <interface>
... snip ...
                                --ssid=<arg>      Specify SSID when creating a PSK
 -h        --help               Show this help
```

Seems to happen with/without sudo, via zsh and bash.

Comment: Can't reproduce on my 10.12.2 machine, so it seems this is not a universal Sierra bug. Stupid question, but is your `en1` interface still behaving normally with other system utilities?

Comment: Thanks @Merlin, you've pointed me in the right direction. I'm very used to en0 being ethernet and en1 being wireless, turns out my Macbook Air (which doesn't have an ethernet port) sets en0 as the interface for wireless! Airport doesn't give a useful error message here still, but that solves the issue!